# Scraping content using pyppeteer in association with asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-asyncio, pyppeteer

I've written a script in python in combination with `pyppeteer` along with `asyncio` to scrape the links of different posts from its landing page and eventually get the title of each post by tracking the url leading to its inner page. The content I parsed here are not dynamic ones. However, I made use of `pyppeteer` and `asyncio` to see how efficiently it performs `asynchronously`.

The following script goes well for some moments but then enounters an error:

```
File "C:\Users\asyncio\tasks.py", line 526, in ensure_future
raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

This is what I've wriiten so far:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

async def fetch(page,url):
    await page.goto(url)
    linkstorage = []
    elements = await page.querySelectorAll('.summary .question-hyperlink')
    for element in elements:
        linkstorage.append(await page.evaluate('(element) => element.href', element))
    tasks = [await browse_all_links(link, page) for link in linkstorage]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results

async def browse_all_links(link, page):
    await page.goto(link)
    title = await page.querySelectorEval('.question-hyperlink','(e => e.innerText)')
    print(title)

async def main(url):
    browser = await launch(headless=True,autoClose=False)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await fetch(page,url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(main(link))
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
    loop.close()
```

***My question: how can I get rid of that error and do the doing asynchronously?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the following lines:

```
tasks = [await browse_all_links(link, page) for link in linkstorage]
results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

The intention is for `tasks` to be a list of awaitable objects, such as coroutine objects or futures. The list is to be passed to `gather`, so that the awaitables can run in parallel until they all complete. However, the list comprehension contains an *await*, which means that it:

- executes each `browser_all_links` to completion **in series** rather than in parallel;
- places the **return values** of `browse_all_links` invocations into the list.

Since `browse_all_links` doesn't return a value, you are passing a list of `None` objects to `asyncio.gather`, which complains that it didn't get an awaitable object.

To resolve the issue, just drop the `await` from the list comprehension.

Comment: I complied with your suggestion and ran the code @user4815162342. This time it gives me another error. The thing is it collects a single title 15 times whereas it is supposed to produce 15 different titles. [Full traceback can be found here](https://pastebin.com/mmVx0euN). Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt Maybe the problem is that you're also sending the same `page` to all coroutines, so they're stepping on each other's toes? You might need to create the `page` in `browse_all_links` instead of in `main`.

Comment: This time I've tried to modify my script exactly as you suggested but still 'm getting a single link 15 times as I mentioned earlier. ***[Check out my current script here](https://pastebin.com/28e3L44V)***. Thanks a lot @ user4815162342.

Comment: @robots.txt You're still sending the same `page` object to all `browse_all_links`. You need to move page creation, i.e. `page = await browser.newPage()`, to `browse_all_links`.

Comment: Now, it appears to be working correctly @ user4815162342. Please ***[check out this link](https://pastebin.com/t7hKGqgv)*** to see what I've done finally.  I'm still unsure I could follow your instruction properly. From the very begining I was trying not to create new browser for new urls as they put a huge load on computer. However, is this what you meant. Thanks a zillion to be with me so far.

Comment: @robots.txt That's what I meant. And, for what it's worth, you're still not creating a new browser per URL, you're creating a new _page_ per URL (I'm not sure if this helps with resource usage since I don't use `pyppeteer`.) Since the page provides the stateful `goto` API, you obviously cannot *both* share the same page among the `browse_all_links` coroutines *and* have them execute in parallel.